# std::chrono default duration for time_since_epoch

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

If I have the following clock and use it to get a count of ticks since the clock's epoch, what does this count actually represent.

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
```

For instance I just ran this and got `1389375799048790227`. What does this number mean? Is it nanoseconds, microseconds, etc?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the `duration` type of the `high_resolution_clock`. Either examine it (nested typedef) or use a `duration_cast` to a known duration type.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the duration is `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration`.  You can inspect a duration's tick period with: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::period::num` and `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::period::den`.  This is the numerator and denominator of a fraction representing the amount of seconds per tick (e.g. 1/1000000000 for nanoseconds).

The epoch is unspecified, but for you is 1389375799048790227 ticks from when you got that result.

Answer (score 6):

you can always cast it to your desired time unit using `duration_cast`

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto time = duration_cast<seconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
```

now `time.count()` will return number of seconds.

Comment: Yes I know I can cast it to something else. But what I'm asking is what happens if I don't cast it? I just call `time_since_epoch()` which returns a duration, and then call `count()`. What does that count mean? What is it a count of?

Comment: @SeanLynch It is the count of ticks of the clock since the epoch of that clock (between the time point and the epoch). How long that tick is is dependent on the `high_resolution_clock` of your Standard Library implementation, similarly, the epoch is also defined by your Standard Library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trick from Item 4 of Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++* to make the compiler reveal the type in an error message, like so:

```
#include <chrono>

template < typename T >
struct TypeDiscloser;

int main() {
    auto epoch_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    TypeDiscloser< decltype( epoch_time ) > dummyVar;
}
```

On [ideone](http://ideone.com/1iMAmX), this gives the following compiler error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:42: error: aggregate 'TypeDiscloser<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > > dummyVar' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  TypeDiscloser< decltype( epoch_time ) > dummyVar;
                                          ^
```

From the compiler error, the type is:

```
std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> >
```

So on whatever platform ideone is running, `std::chrono::time_point::time_since_epoch()` returns a `std::chrono::duration` with a tick period of 1/1000000000 seconds, or 1 nanosecond.  So calling `count()` on that duration returns nanoseconds.