# How to convert std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() to Windows File Time (and reverse conversion)

Tags: winapi, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to easily convert std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() time to Windows File Time (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx) (and back)? I have no idea how to deal with this...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you have (or may have) a 100nanosecond or better precision time_point:

```
FILETIME fileTime = {0};

// Filetime has a resolution of 100nanoseconds
typedef std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio_multiply<std::hecto, std::nano>> hundrednanoseconds;

// 100nanoseconds since unix epoch + epoch offset difference of filetime
long long timePointTmp =
    std::chrono::duration_cast<hundrednanoseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count() 
    + 116444736000000000;

fileTime.dwLowDateTime = (unsigned long)timePointTmp;
fileTime.dwHighDateTime = timePointTmp >> 32;

return fileTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert `time_point` to a `time_t`, then use the following function to convert it to a FILETIME.

```
std::time_t t;
t = to_time_t(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
```

Then convert to FILETIME (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

void TimetToFileTime( time_t t, LPFILETIME pft )
{
    LONGLONG ll = Int32x32To64(t, 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
    pft->dwLowDateTime = (DWORD) ll;
    pft->dwHighDateTime = ll >>32;
}
```

Also, remember on windows the `high_resolution_clock` is implemented as the not-so-high-res `system_clock`

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution based on yours and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050994/stdchrono-default-duration-for-time-since-epoch, which can be used for system_clock as well, it is more precise than std::time_t, as std::time_t represents time in seconds.

Comment: VS 2015 will fix the high_resolution_clock :)

Comment: consider that this converison will lose all sub-second resolution (so the high_resolution_clock resolution doesn't make much of a difference)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the right solution:

```
FILETIME fileTime = { 0 };
long long timePointTmp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() * 10 + 116444736000000000;
fileTime.dwLowDateTime = (unsigned long)timePointTmp;
fileTime.dwHighDateTime = timePointTmp >> 32;
```